# Android, realm. How to query all objects not attached to owners?

Tags: android, realm

```
public class Person extends RealmObject {

    private Dog dog;
}

public class Dog extends RealmObject {

     @LinkingObjects("dog")
     private final RealmResults<PoolElement> owners = null;
}
```

Hi! Does anybody know if there's a way to query all Dogs not attached to any person?

Comment: Have you tried `realm.where(Dog.class).isEmpty("owners").findAll()`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce It works, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
realm.where(Dog.class).isEmpty("owners").findAll()
```